# How to achieve two inputs next to each other?

Tags: html, css, forms

every time when I have to work with *Inputs* this problem occurs.

My goal is to make a simple input form and achieve that 2 Inputs type number will be the same width, with small space between them in one line, just under "Description" input.

I've tried to add them to divs and apply Display:inline-block to them, but it didn't work. Now I've tried to apply display: flex on it a this is the result. Changing the width of input does not work. Thank you for your help.

```css
.inputBox{
  width: 30%;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: .3em;
}

.inputBox h3{
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.inputBox input[type="text"]{
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 1em 0;
  border-radius: .3em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inputBox input[type="number"]{
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: .3em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

label{
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.flex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div className="inputBox">
  <h3>Please set your alarm</h3>

  <label for="text">Description</label>
  <input type="text" id="text" />

  <div className="flex">
    <div className="inputNumber">
      <label>Hours</label>
      <input type="number" />
    </div>
                            
  <div className="inputNumber">
    <label>Minutes</label>
    <input type="number" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The problem you describe, as I read it, is solved in the screenshot you provided. Could you clarify what it is that you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. My goal is that two inputs which I've displayed next to each other using Display flex have large gap between (I mean gap should be as big as the gap between Hours and Description input) and width of those 2 input should be bigger @Dan Mullin.

Comment: The code you provided does not produce the result you show in the screenshot. However, if you're already at the point displayed in the screenshot and just want less space between the Hours and Minutes inputs, you can increase the `width` of input number to `49%` or to `calc(50% - 5px)`

Comment: when I set input number width to 49% ,width of input reduces by half. to be more clear i will edit my question

Comment: `.inputBox input[type="number"] {width: auto; flex: 1;}`

Comment: does not change the width or gap. I don't get that what is the problem. I'm going to create codesandbox for you so you can see whole code

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-http-lqdcu?file=/src/App.js here is link for sandbox. There is button in right top corner,which will call Alert component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    .inputBox{
      width: 30%;
      padding: 2em;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: .3em;
    }

    .inputBox h3{
      font-size: 2em;
      font-weight: 300;
    }

    .inputBox input[type="text"]{
      width: 100%;
      padding: .5em;
      margin: 1em 0;
      border-radius: .3em;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .inputBox input[type="number"]{
      padding: .5em;
      border-radius: .3em;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
    }

    label{
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .flex{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
.inputNumber{
  flex-basis:48%;
} 
    <div class="inputBox">
      <h3>Please set your alarm</h3>

      <label for="text">Description</label>
      <input type="text" id="text" />

      <div class="flex">
        <div class="inputNumber">
          <label>Hours</label>
          <input type="number" />
        </div>
                                
      <div class="inputNumber">
        <label>Minutes</label>
        <input type="number" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: just add .inputNumber{
  flex-basis:48%;
}  to your css and it will do the job.

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution for my problem. Definitely gonna take note somewhere with this line of code. This is my problem for ages ,when it comes to work with inputs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep inputBox's width at 30%, you can do something like this:
**HTML**

```
<div class="inputBox">
        <h3>Please set your alarm</h3>

        <label for="text">Description</label>
        <input type="text" id="text" />

        <div class="flex">
            <div class="inputNumber">
                <label>Hours</label>
                <input type="number" />
            </div>

            <div class="inputNumber second">
                <label>Minutes</label>
                <input type="number" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.inputBox {
        width: 30%;
        padding: 2em;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: .3em;
    }

    .inputBox h3 {
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    .inputBox input[type="text"] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: .5em;
        margin: 1em 0;
        border-radius: .3em;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .inputBox input[type="number"] {
        padding: .5em;
        border-radius: .3em;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
    }

    label {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .flex {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;

    }

    .inputNumber {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .second {
        margin-left: 5%;
    }
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

two problems:

1. you are using className when you should be using class
2. change .inputBox width to 100%

also, you should ALWAYS try to post a working snippet that shows your problem.  You will get back answers faster and ones that are more likely to work!

```css
.inputBox{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: .3em;
}

.inputBox h3{
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.inputBox input[type="text"]{
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 1em 0;
  border-radius: .3em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inputBox input[type="number"]{
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: .3em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

label{
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.flex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputBox">
  <h3>Please set your alarm</h3>

  <label for="text">Description</label>
  <input type="text" id="text" />

  <div class="flex">
    <div class="inputNumber">
      <label>Hours</label>
      <input type="number" />
    </div>
                            
  <div class="inputNumber">
    <label>Minutes</label>
    <input type="number" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No thats not problem. className I'm using on purpose. This is just little code extracted from my React App ,and in React it's written like that.. And with I don't want to set to 100% because it is supposed to be just small input box,which is React Component and renders on button click @DCR

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display: grid` on your parent and modify the first child of grid to span across the first line like:

```css
.parentContainer { 
   /* this will create the grid for us with 1rem gap between children */
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr),
   grid-gap: 1rem;
}


.theChildElementYouWantToFullWidth {
   grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}
```

for more information check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) doc from MDN on Grid styling!